# Image pixel manipulation: Use native APIs or 3rd party libraries?

Tags: java, image-processing, bit-manipulation, pixel

I need to write an application in Java which need to be able to manipulate the pixels of an image regardless of the format of the image (**JPEG**, **BitMap**, **Gif**, ...).

It means I need to access the pixels and also I need to calculate some attributes of the image such as **size**, **resolution**, **contrast**, **brightness** and the **compression algorithm**.

I also need to manipulate the bits of individual pixels.
Now what I need to know is that can I do these by means of pure **Java SE** classes or I need to use a third party library? If so, which is the best for me? *JAI*, *ImageJ*, ...?

Comment: Using ImageJ sounds like a good idea to me. I've used it successfully as a Java routine to import rather-obscure image data formats...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java Advanced Imagining API FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html) and you should be able to decide from it whether you want to use the native Java APIs or a 3rd-party library. (The concept of manipulating pixels can vary tremendously in complexity. The examples you mentioned are not difficult but other operations may be.) Getting the size, resolution and compression alg is somewhat trivial as they are all attributes of the objects you use in image manipulation. (Though resolution is relative.) Working with contrast and brightness is a little more involved but not much. See [here for an interesting sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ImageProcessingBrightnessandContrast.htm). Java2s has lots of Java image-manipulation snippets available .

Here's a [link directly to the Supported File Formats section](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html#fileformat) in the FAQ.

JAI Hello World:

```
PlanarImage source = JAI.create("fileload", file);
```

> This function automatically determines
>   the file format and produces an image
>   object which can be displayed or
>   processed.

Comment: Where can I download JAI for JDK 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: This looks like the latest & greatest: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-1_1_2.html

Comment: Thanks I've already downloaded it but it seems very difficult to find tutorials! :( I need only some basic functions.

Comment: Have you seen/tried this: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/javaai/jai/index.html